# Error with console.readLine(); but everything looks correct in code?

Tags: java

When I try to run this it says there is a problem with the `console.readLine();`.

```
import java.io.Console;

public class PingPong {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("give me a number, honey?");
    String stringYourNumber = console.readLine();
    Integer yourNumber = Integer.parseInt(stringYourNumber);

    System.out.println("Here ya go:");
    for ( Integer i=1; i <=yourNumber; i++){
        if( i % 5==0 && i % 3==0){
            System.out.println("PingPong");
        } else {
            if (i % 5==0){
                System.out.println("Pong");
            } else {
                if ( i % 3==0){
                    System.out.println("Ping");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it say _some problem_ or **this specific problem right here with this error message that happens for this reason**?

Comment: PingPong.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
  String stringYourNumber = console.readLine();
                            ^
  symbol:   variable console
  location: class PingPong
1 error

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant information and explain what you don't understand about the error message.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the error possibly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare and intialize a variable called console

```
Console console = System.console();
if (console != null)  {
    str = console.readline ();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Scary Wombat, I JUST saw this was missing in my code and came back here to see you answer. Thank you for not being a troll!

Comment: That's Ok.  if I answer your question please consider to upvote and/or accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a little bit on this problem. And below is the solution.

import java.io.Console;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("give me a number, honey?");
    Console con = null;
    String stringYourNumber = null;
try {
con = System.console();
        if (con != null) {
            stringYourNumber = con.readLine("give me a number, honey?");
            Integer yourNumber = Integer.parseInt(stringYourNumber);
            System.out.println("Here ya go:");
            for (Integer i = 1; i <= yourNumber; i++) {

                if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) {

                    System.out.println("PingPong");
                } else {
                    if (i % 5 == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Pong");

                    } else {
                        if (i % 3 == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Ping");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
} catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The method you were using with your code is actually native to C#. However that feature can be tweaked in here too. However now you next job is to find the how to enter java's console. Also notice that We are not treating console as a class but its inbuilt function. And You can determine that by the fact we didn't create any object with new Console().

I hope this helps you.